# В тригере на postgres в цикле обратиться к перменным OLD.current_column_name / NEW.current_column_name

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, триггер, plpgsql

Всем здравствуйте.
Пишучи тригер на plpgsql, я пытаюсь в цикле получить старое и новое значение каждой колонки таблицы. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как правильно использовать эту переменную в выражении типа `OLD.current_column_name` и `NEW.current_column_name`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_stamp$
DECLARE
  current_column_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR current_column_name IN
    SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.Columns 
    WHERE table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA AND table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME 
    LOOP
      IF (OLD."current_column_name" <> NEW."current_column_name")
      then ...
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_function();
```

Мне выдает следующую ошибку: `ERROR: record "old" has no field "current_column_name"`
Я пытался по-разному експерементировать с кавычками, но так ничего и не получилось. В результате мне нужно выписать измененные значения с таблицы в следующем виде: `column_name`, `old_value` и `new_value`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку NEW и OLD являются переменными типа RECORD, вы можете обратиться к их полям как к элементам массива при использовании [plv8](https://github.com/plv8/plv8):

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_fn() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
  for (var key in OLD) {
    NEW[key]=OLD[key];
  }
  return NEW;
$$
LANGUAGE plv8;
```

Кстати, полезная иногда функция :-)

Answer (score 1):

Обратиться к имени колонки через переменную в plpgsql нельзя. Исторический ответ - используйте другие встраиваемые языки. Много их есть.

Зато для задачи "найти разницу и залогировать" можно не привязываться к типу record, а воспользоваться JSON. Функция [`row_to_json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), принимающая record и отдающая json вполне себе уже давно существует аж с далёкого postgresql 9.2, где из всей обработки json и были только array_to_json и row_to_json. Правда, этих функций будет недостаточно для задачи определения разницы между строками. Так что нужен pg посвежее или переписать с использованием функций [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) - там тоже есть вариант создания hstore из record и уже давно много функций по обработке данных.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_stamp$
DECLARE
  rowdiff json;
BEGIN

select json_object_agg(key, json_build_object('old', o.value, 'new', n.value))
into rowdiff
    from json_each(row_to_json(NEW.*)) n
        full outer join json_each(row_to_json(OLD.*)) o using(key)
    where o.value::text != n.value::text;

raise notice '%', rowdiff;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

В результате в `rowdiff` будет json-объект различий между строками вроде такого:

```
update test set val=4 where id=1;
NOTICE:  { "val" : {"old" : 3, "new" : 4} }
UPDATE 1
```

У меня под рукой оказался только postgresql 9.4, в котором ещё отсутствуют функции `jsonb_object_agg`, `jsonb_build_object`, поэтому в примере используется текстовый json.

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет расширение [hstore](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/hstore)
Должно получиться что-то вроде такого (не тестировал)

```
FOR _attr IN
  SELECT o.key AS key
    , o.value AS old_value
    , n.value AS new_value
  FROM each(hstore(OLD)) o
    INNER JOIN each(hstore(NEW)) n
  WHERE o.value <> n.value
LOOP
  RAISE NOTICE 'Изменилась колонка % с ''%'' на ''%''', _attr.key, _attr.old_value, _attr.new_value;
END LOOP;
```

Не забудьте, что это расширение, которое надо устанавливать (хотя это очень легко и быстро). Как это сделать, сказано, например, [тут](http://evtuhovich.ru/blog/2012/01/23/hstore/)